# Doctrine "A new entity was found through the relationship" error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

First off I want to say I've read through all the docs and googled this plenty before posting this question. I know what that error means (un-persisted entity in a relationship)

I'm getting this error where I think I shouldn't be getting it.

I have a **OneToMany Bi-Directional** relationship as follow:

```
Class Channel
{
    /** 
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Step", mappedBy="channel", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"sequence" = "ASC"})
    */
    protected $steps;
}

Class Step
{
    /** 
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Channel", inversedBy="steps")
    */
    protected $channel;
}
```

One `Channel` can have many `Step`s and the owning side is `Channel`. After I upgraded from Doctrine **2.4** to **2.5** I'm getting this error:

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found
>   through the relationship 'Company\MyBundle\Entity\Step#channel' that
>   was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity

**why is it even finding new relationships from the inverse side?** Here's my code:

```
$channel = new Channel();
$step = new Step();
$channel->addStep($step);
$em->persist($channel);
$em->flush();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `Channel::addStep()` look like?

Comment: You did not specify the join column on the Step entity. So Doctrine does not know how to save it.

Comment: If One Channel can have many Steps then I think the owning side is Step entity, not the Channel entity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right: Doctrine looks only for changes into owning side but you're wrong: owning side of your relationship is `Step`, not `Channel`.

Why is step the owning side? Because is the entity that has foreign key. Even Doctrine documentation says to you

> The owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute
>   contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.

#### Possible solutions:

- Try to invert cascade operations by putting `cascade={"all"}` into Step entity (are you sure that ***all*** is the correct choice?)
- Persist explicitly both entities:

  ```
  $channel = new Channel();
  $step = new Step();
  $channel->addStep($step);
  $em->persist($channel);
  $em->persist($step);
  $em->flush();
  ```

  [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) you can read why second way provided here is fine too

Comment: Thanks, I moved `cascade` to the Step entity and that helped! When you want a relationship to cascade, when would you not want to have `all` ?

Comment: Can I have cascade on both sides of the relationship? Because most of the time I'm going through Channel

Comment: @RezaS All means every cascade operation (persist, REMOVE, and so on) so, maybe, sometimes you don't want to delete a channel if you remove a step (just to make an example) and of course you can use cascade operations on both side but this depends on your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

You try to persist `$channel`, but it has `Step` entity inside. So in Doctrine now you have 2 entities that are queued for inserting. Then Doctrine order entities in the order where first is `Step` because it has `channel_id` foreign key (that is empty now). Doctrine try persist this entity and when it understands that `channel_id` is empty it sees for cascade rules for persisting. It doesn't see any cascade rules and throw you this exception.

Comment: No, here the foreign key is hold by channel, not the opposite (the owning side is the side where foreign keys are holded and here the owning side is channel)

Comment: In the database you will have column `channel_id` in `Step` table because you have relation **One** `Channel` - **To** - **Many** `Steps`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I dind't saw the file names and get confused about.